# How many TCP segments are required to establish a TCP connection?

Tags: tcp

How many TCP segments are required to establish a TCP connection? What important control information is carried in these TCP segments, and why?

Comment: You need to read the implementation off the TCP protocol.  That will help you immensly.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) is the wikipedia article on TCP and [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) is the RFC. In the future, don't just paste your assignments verbatim.

Comment: YOu can also contact me .......................all my class fellows